# Execute "find -exec" on remote maching using ksh

Tags: find, exec, ksh

I am not sure if this belongs to superuser. Please excuse.
Here is what I am trying to do. I need to create a ksh script which will establish an ssh connection to a remote machine and find all ".tar" files in a particular path for a particular date and list them. Next, I will need to perform an scp command to copy all those .tar files to the server I am executing the ksh script on. 
Here is what I have so far and it is far from complete... (please bear with me.. I am very new to ksh scripting).

Can someone please advise if I am going in the right direction and provide some pointers as to how I can improve and achieve what I am trying to do?

Many thanks in advance.

```
SSERVER=server1
SOURCEPATH=/tmp/test

sudo ssh $SSERVER \
find $SOURCEPATH -name "*.tar" -mtime +7 -exec ls {} \;
#will the above two statements work?
#I then need to output the ls results to a temp variable (i believe) and issue an scp on each of the files

#Copy files from SOURCEPATH to PATH
sudo scp "$SSERVER:$SOURCEPATH/$file1" /tftpboot
sudo scp "$SSERVER:$SOURCEPATH/$file2" /tftpboot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SSERVER=server1
SOURCEPATH=/tmp/test

sudo ssh "$SSERVER" "find $SOURCEPATH -name '*.tar' -mtime +7" |
  while IFS= read -r; do
    sudo scp "$SSERVER:'$REPLY'" /tftpboot
  done
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. your answer lead me down the right path to get it to work the way I needed it to!